# Remove publishing restrictions on all the Sitecore nodes

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I want to create a Sitecore powershell script which goes through the content trees and removes any present publishing restrictions

Everywhere I have seen, there are examples of how to publish an item. 
I don't want to publish the item. I want to remove the publishing restrictions recursively in Sitecore powershell. 
If there is any restriction on Publishing target, or any date restriction already imposed, or if any item is made not to publish by removing the tick mark, I want to reset it all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a SQL query to locate items with publishing restrictions](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/Investigating-why-something-was-not-published#check-publishing-restrictions).

You might want to modify it slightly to remove those rows & restart Sitecore.

Do a backup before any data removal to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Fields that control the Publishing Restrictions. Some fields are shared, other not, so an item with multiple version and or multiple languages can contain different values. so you need to iterate in all items and all versions to remove all publish restrictions.

In Sitecore PowerShell you can do this with this script (for items below \content\Home):

```
foreach($item in Get-ChildItem -Path master:\content\Home -Recurse) {
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["__Publishing groups"] = ""
$item["__Publish"] = ""
$item["__Never publish"] =""
$item["__Unpublish"] =""
$item.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null
foreach ($version in $item.Versions.GetVersions($true))
 {
        $version.Editing.BeginEdit()
        $version["__Valid from"] =""
        $version["__Valid to"] =""
        $version["__Hide version"] =""
        $version.Editing.EndEdit()  | Out-Null
 }
}
```

Note: The __Workflow state is not in the script, it is not part of the publishing restrictions functionality but it can block a publish. If wanted you can also add it.

See [Fields that Control Publishing Restrictions in the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/fields-that-control-publishing-restrictions-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms)